# Adding Group Item in QuickBooks using QBFC

Tags: vb.net, qbfc

Need a little help here.

I just want to add a Group Item with Item List on it using the QBFC12 but am having a trouble with it. I have tried creating the same method like this with Inventory Assembly and it works well. but this one makes me feel terrible. When the request is processed, it return error telling that there're missing fields on the request. Hope anyone can help me out with this.

Thanks

Here's my code below:

```
Dim msgSetRequest As IMsgSetRequest

Dim QBSM As New QBSessionManager

Try

    With QBSM

        .OpenConnection("", "QB Test")

        .BeginSession("", ENOpenMode.omDontCare)

    End With

Catch ex As Exception

    Throw New Exception(ex.Message)

    Return False

End Try

msgSetRequest = QBSM.CreateMsgSetRequest("US", 8, 0)
msgSetRequest.Attributes.OnError = ENRqOnError.roeStop

msgSetRequest.ClearRequests()

Dim gAdd As IItemGroupAdd = msgSetRequest.AppendItemGroupAddRq
gAdd.IsActive.SetValue(True)

gAdd.Name.SetValue("Group Name")

gAdd.ItemDesc.SetValue("Group Description")



For Each gListItem As clsInventoryGroupItem In gItem.InventoryGroupItemList

       Dim gItemAdd As IItemGroupLine = msgSetRequest.AppendItemGroupAddRq.ItemGroupLineList.Append

       gItemAdd.ItemRef.FullName.SetValue(gListItem.ItemRef)

       gItemAdd.Quantity.SetValue(gListItem.Quantity)

Next



Dim response As IMsgSetResponse = QBSM.DoRequests(msgSetRequest)

If response.ResponseList.GetAt(0).StatusCode = 0 Then

     MessageBox.Show("Success")

else

     MessageBox.Show("An Error occurred while inserting Group")

endif
```

Answer (score 0):

I think the problem is how you are adding your group lines, but haven't tested it yet. Instead of using ItemGroupLineList.Append from the msgSetRequest, you should call it from your IItemGroupAdd object, gAdd. Here's what I came up with, but didn't test it.

```
Dim msgSetRequest As IMsgSetRequest

Dim QBSM As New QBSessionManager

Try

    With QBSM

        .OpenConnection("", "QB Test")

        .BeginSession("", ENOpenMode.omDontCare)

    End With

Catch ex As Exception

    Throw New Exception(ex.Message)

    Return False

End Try

msgSetRequest = QBSM.CreateMsgSetRequest("US", 8, 0)
msgSetRequest.Attributes.OnError = ENRqOnError.roeStop

msgSetRequest.ClearRequests()

Dim gAdd As IItemGroupAdd = msgSetRequest.AppendItemGroupAddRq
gAdd.IsActive.SetValue(True)

gAdd.Name.SetValue("Group Name")

gAdd.ItemDesc.SetValue("Group Description")



For Each gListItem As clsInventoryGroupItem In gItem.InventoryGroupItemList

       Dim gItemAdd As IItemGroupLine = gAdd.ItemGroupLineList.Append

       gItemAdd.ItemRef.FullName.SetValue(gListItem.ItemRef)

       gItemAdd.Quantity.SetValue(gListItem.Quantity)

Next



Dim response As IMsgSetResponse = QBSM.DoRequests(msgSetRequest)

If response.ResponseList.GetAt(0).StatusCode = 0 Then

     MessageBox.Show("Success")

else

     MessageBox.Show("An Error occurred while inserting Group")

endif
```